# Reddit API and voting. Not accepting modhash/cookie. .error.USER_REQUIRED

Tags: python, api, reddit

I'm trying to get the voting API working, but I get the error .error.USER_REQUIRED. Can't figure out why, but I assume I must either be sending the modhash or the session cookie the wrong way, as the login goes trough fine

My code looks something like this:

```
UP = {'user': username, 'passwd': password, 'api_type': 'json',}

client = requests.session()

r = client.post('http://www.reddit.com/api/login', data=UP)

j = json.loads(r.text)

mymodhash = j['json']['data']['modhash']

url = 'http://www.reddit.com/api/vote/.json'
postdata = {'id': thing, 'dir': newdir, 'uh': mymodhash}
vote = client.post(url, data=json.dumps(newdata))
```

Error:

```
{"jquery": [[0, 1, "refresh", []], [0, 2, "attr", "find"], [2, 3, "call", [".error.USER_REQUIRED"]], [3, 4, "attr", "show"], [4, 5, "call", []], [5, 6, "attr", "text"], [6, 7, "call", ["please login to do that"]], [7, 8, "attr", "end"], [8, 9, "call", []]]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To login you *should* post to `ssl.reddit.com` so that you are not posting your credentials in plain-text. Also, you should set a User-Agent.

The below is a working example to vote on your /r/redditdev submission.

```
import requests
# Login                                                                                                
client = requests.session(headers={'User-Agent': 'Requests test'})
data = {'user': 'USERNAME', 'passwd': 'PASSWORD', 'api_type': 'json'}
r = client.post('https://ssl.reddit.com/api/login', data=data)
modhash = r.json['json']['data']['modhash']

# Vote                                                                                                 
data = {'id': 't3_11mr32', 'dir': '1', 'uh': modhash, 'api_type': 'json'}
r = client.post('http://www.reddit.com/api/vote', data=data)
print r.status_code  # Should be 200                                                                   
print r.json  # Should be {}
```

Also, unless you are really interested in how reddit's API works under the covers, I suggest you use [PRAW](https://github.com/praw-dev/praw/).

Comment: What is 'User-Agent': 'Requests test'?

Comment: That indicates to Reddit that you are a client identified as `Requests test`. According to Reddit's API this user agent should be quite a bit more descriptive: https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API#rules. It's also worth noting that Reddit's API doesn't officially support cookie-auth anymore for third party clients so you really should look into OAuth.

Answer (score 0):

You can use session object with `with` statement.

```
import requests

UP = {'user': username, 'passwd': password, 'api_type': 'json'}
url_prefix = "http://www.reddit.com"
with requests.session() as client:
    client.post(url_prefix + '/login', data=UP)

    <...something else what you want...>
```

Comment: I've tried that now, still not accepting the login. I've also tried getting the modhash from http://www.reddit.com/api/me.json, still refuses. I figure I must misunderstand how the modhash works, maybe it changes because of the way i request the URL's. Might also be the cookie I guess.